# Upper bound for the variance of an inner product between two $L^2$ functions, one of them is deterministic

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Assume that we have $g,h$ are two $L^2(\mathbb{R}^{+})$ functions, where $g$ is deterministic and $h$ is random. I want to bound $Var[\langle g,h\rangle]$ with $Var[h]$ so I minimize the former by just minimizing the latter ($\langle,\rangle$ is the inner product). One way that I thought about it is to use the delta method which gives me 
$$ Var[ b(h)] \approx \left(b'(\operatorname{E}\left[h\right])\right)^2\operatorname{Var}\left[h\right]$$
Where $b:h \rightarrow \langle g,h\rangle$

Is there any simpler way to do that??

I replied to this question below but I am wondering if we could obtain sharper bound? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think we can also bound this variance with $E[\mid \mid h \mid \mid^2]$ up to a constant.  In fact, we have 
$$Var[<g,h>] \leq E[<g,h>^2]$$
and since using Cauchy Schwartz, we have $<g,h>^2 \leq \mid \mid g \mid \mid^2 \mid \mid h \mid \mid^2$. Then
$$   E[<g,h>^2] \leq E \left[\mid \mid g \mid \mid^2 \mid \mid h \mid \mid^2\right]= \mid \mid g \mid \mid^2  E \left[\mid \mid h \mid \mid^2\right].$$